# Create Overlay Image on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i want make a "startup tip" on my app but im not sure how i should make it. I want something like in Jelly bean when you start as the first time, i want a "hand" that indicate you can swype to left or right something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library, it works wonders: https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Comment: its not what im looking for, perhaps its a nice lib and could "help" i will mark as acceptep because its the same as the picture i upload thanks a lot.